Building Cassandra from source on Windows 11 fails with "NoSuchMethodError: 'java_cup.runtime.SymbolFactory jflex.core.LexParse.getSymbolFactory()'"
Running ant in the root directory of Cassandra is yielding me a BUILD FAILED. I've tried with ant versions 1.10.11, 1.10.13, and the latest 1.10.14.
I found the same issue on JIRA, link to it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16831
When building with the latest ant version 1.10.14, I'm getting the following:

generate-jflex-java:

BUILD FAILED
C:\cassandra\build.xml:489: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java_cup.runtime.SymbolFactory jflex.core.LexParse.getSymbolFactory()'
        at jflex.core.LexParse$CUP$LexParse$actions.CUP$LexParse$do_action_part00000000(LexParse.java:1087)
        at jflex.core.LexParse$CUP$LexParse$actions.CUP$LexParse$do_action(LexParse.java:2257)
        at jflex.core.LexParse.do_action(LexParse.java:598)
        at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.parse(lr_parser.java:569)
        at jflex.generator.LexGenerator.generate(LexGenerator.java:74)
        at jflex.anttask.JFlexTask.execute(JFlexTask.java:78)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

So similar to the JIRA issue, the build fails with generate-jflex-java, couldn't find a fix for this. So I tried changing ant version.
With versions 1.10.11 and  1.10.13, generate-jflex-java works with no hiccups, but hits a snag afterwards:
_check-test-names:
[check-test-names] Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 31: C:\cassandra/build/test/classes:C:\cassandra/build/test/fqltool-classes:C:\cassandra/build/test/stress-classes
[check-test-names]      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
[check-test-names]      at org.apache.cassandra.anttasks.TestNameCheckTask.lambda$execute$0(TestNameCheckTask.java:98)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
[check-test-names]      at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
[check-test-names]      at org.apache.cassandra.anttasks.TestNameCheckTask.execute(TestNameCheckTask.java:107)
[check-test-names]      at org.apache.cassandra.anttasks.TestNameCheckTask.main(TestNameCheckTask.java:192)

BUILD FAILED
C:\cassandra\build.xml:1018: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\cassandra\build.xml:1091: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\cassandra\build.xml:1069: Java returned: 1

Can't really seem to figure out where the issue is. I'm running a Windows 11, and am using JDK 11. I've also tried switching and building with JDK 17 just to see if it had anything to do with JDK version but no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATE
Build was successful!
The combination of Java 17 and ant 1.10.13 yielded a successful build. Unsure of what to make of it, but I'd still really like to know why.
Doesn't work. I was actually doing ant build which resulted in a successful build but that doesn't fully build the project as ant does.
So, if anyone wants to chime in and help, would greatly appreciate it! The same errors persist.
